# Dividing with big(ish) numbers in C (Get a zero, when I know it isn't zero)

Tags: python, c, math, double, division

Okay, so I have already proved that the answer is -7.98392238758e-07 in python in about 20 seconds, but why can I not receive the same answer in C (I get zero).

```
double x = 1255060;
double y = -1571985829941;

double z = x/y;

printf("\nZ is %f", z);
```

Originally I thought that the issue was that I needed to use a long long instead of a double, but I still receive the same answer of 0.

I am very intrigued to know the solution to this annoying problem.

Comment: Put a dot in all your constants: `double x=1255060.0;` and the `\n` at *end* of `printf` format string. Use `%g` format in `printf`. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ ; perhaps you want to use http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Out of curiosity what does the %g do in comparison to %f? Does it just put it into scientific format?

Comment: Read [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), it i s a very useful read.

Comment: @Basile: It's not necessary to add the dot to the constants in C.

Comment: Are you sure about those numbers, Lockey? With Python 2.6 I get 1255060./-1571985829941 = -7.983914206447428e-07

Comment: Or if you want a bit more precision : -7.9839142064474276706300833720410666290487000961795395481870e-07

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example gives the expected answer (under clang):

```
Z is -0.000001
```

(which is the same as -7.98392238758e-07 rounded upwards)

You can use the `%e` format placeholder in `printf` to make it use scientific notation, in the same manner as what python uses.

```
double x = 1255060;
double y = -1571985829941;

double z = x/y;

printf("\nX is %f", x);
printf("\nY is %f", y);
printf("\nZ is %e", z);
```

Output

```
X is 1255060.000000
Y is -1571985829941.000000
Z is -7.983914e-07
```

Comment: I suppose `%g` would be better :)

Comment: Depends. In this case I wanted scientific notation, so it's better to ask for it explicitly.